# Emailing Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a script that will send emails to affiliates. There is a Javascript code that I want to email to clients. But when I email Javascript code, Outlook and other web email clients interpret this code as Javascript. I want them to read this Javascript code as a string or normal text. `<pre>` and `<code>` tags didn't work for me. Even my browser treats this code as Javascript.

Also I would like to tell that I'm using the TinyMCE as editor to write emails.

```
<script>
  //some code goes here
</script>
```

I want to email this as normal text and want to show in the browser.

Comment: it is not programming question..

Comment: @MR E can't send link..got to send script.

Comment: @alex is it not programming question? then wht is it ?

Comment: @alexanderb Arguably it’s programming *related*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want it to be readable instead of executable, why not html encode it ?
cant imagine they pick up "&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;test&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;" as javascript.

also, you can just attach a file with the code in it, just don't name it .js

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you don't want your javascript to execute on client machines and only want them to be visible.

- You can send a clear text email
- Try replacing < , > with &lt; &gt; if you must send and HTML
  formatted email

Answer (score -1):

Any sensible email client will ignore JavaScript, for obvious reasons.